# Internal server error: Buffer cannot be null after deploying my WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have just deployed my ASP.NET application to a remote server with a hosting company and when I try to send my POST request in postman to my URL, I get an internal server error with the following error message.

> "Message": "An error has occurred."
>
> "ExceptionMessage": "Buffer cannot be null. Parameter name: buffer"
>
> "ExceptionType": "System.ArgumentNullException"

The StackTrace information is pointing to my AccountController on line 334.

below is my AccountController:

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        else
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream(model.ImageArray);//This is the line the StackTrace Points to
            var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var file = string.Format("{0}.jpg", guid);
            var folder = "~\\Content\\UserData";
            var fullpath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", folder, file);
            var response = Filehelpers.UploadPhoto(stream, folder, file);


            var user = new ApplicationUser()
            {
                UserName = model.Alias,
                Email = model.Email,
                Alias = model.Alias,
                PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber,
                DateJoined = model.DateJoined,
                ImagePath = fullpath



            };

            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                return GetErrorResult(result);
            }

            return Ok();
```

Here is my Model:

```
[Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    //custom models

    //represents the username
    public string Alias { get; set; }
    //represents when the user signed up
    public DateTime DateJoined { get; set; }
    //represents users profile picture
    [NotMapped]
    public byte[] ImageArray { get; set; }
    //represents the uri of the users picture
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

PS: It was working fine locally when i was testing but started throwing the Error when i deployed and wanted to test.

Comment: You are deploying on to the internet a Web Application that stores clear text passwords?

Comment: @Lankymart isn't this also a possible duplicate? Someone must've asked what an arguementnulleception is by now.

Comment: @Jlalonde absolutely, you're welcome to go find one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is this code throwing an ArgumentNullException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261257/why-is-this-code-throwing-an-argumentnullexception)

Comment: @Lankymart, no I'm not storing it in clear text. It's a hashed password

Comment: @Classyk regardless of how you store it in the database you still expose it in the model.

Answer (score 1):

What that exception is telling us is you're attempting to call a method with a null argument. Thus it's invalid. It seems the  Image Array is the culprit here

So we need to fix this in one two ways. We need to add a `[Required]` attribute to our image array so this doesn't happen in the future.

We also need to make sure the request were sending to our API is properly formatted and contains an image array.

Comment: I will try the required attribute option but I sure have my json data propertlly formatted and it contains an image array cos I was sending the same data when the database was still local. And now that I deployed it online, the error is showing up.

Comment: Interesting. I personally have never tried to send an image in a post, so maybe see if your json is truly formatted _and_ that newtonsoft can support such serialization

Comment: Ok but I am only having this problem after I deployed my API online. I checked and can confirm that newtonsoft supports the serialization. I don't even know what to think anymore.

Comment: Interesting. Are you hitting through a gateway? Log exactly what you're getting in to your API from the HTTP context, maybe a header is being discarded. Let's break the debugging down into parts. 1 what an I sending. 2 what I receiving, 3 what is my code doing.

Comment: To be honest, I do not clearly understand what you mean. All I know is I used to work with Azure for API deployment and it works perfectly but it got too expensive and I decided to try something else and I have all these problems. I don't understand what you mean by gateway?

Comment: An API gateway is a server that stands in front of your API for security. Read more [here](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) about AWS's API gateway. Now for the debugging let's access the controls HTTP context and log what were receiving to test. [Read about Http Context here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because `model.ImageArray` is coming null. To prove the point you can simply log `model.ImageArray` in the server and check.

My Suggestion would be to safeguard your `ImageArray` with null or empty check and return badrequest if not passed in the POST body.

Comment: I know the image array is returning null and I want a way to be able to rectify the issue. I will put it in check for null and see what happens. But I was sending the same data while the database was local and it worked fine. But now that I put it online, the issue starting showing up

Comment: Assuming that website hosting company is using IIS servers, my guess is POST body exceeding the maxrequest length. By default it comes with 2 megs but hosting server may overwrite the default.  Can you try setting the follwoing two property in your webconfig maxAllowedContentLength and maxRequestLength.  you can find more about this [here](https://webconnection.west-wind.com/docs/_4lp0zgm9d.htm). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You got that error because the  var stream = new MemoryStream(model.ImageArray) returned null. The null was because the column for model.ImageArray was missing or null. All you need to do is re-insert the value of the Base64 model.ImageArray. I had similar issue, you open the edit button and re-upload the line and column that the "ImageArray". See my example my model.ImageData can't be null.
[image]